# Aminoacid screening library in Knime

Tags: workflow, knime, molecule

I have a task to create tetrapeptide screening library aminoacids using Knime. I have never used Knime before sadly. I need to create a workflow with all 20 aminoacids, multiply it with another 20, then multiply the result with another 20 and repeat to get final result of tetrapeptides. Can someone suggest me how to input aminoacids on the Knime? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Table Creator` node to enter the Amino acid single-letter codes, one per table.  Now use a `Cross Joiner` node to cross-join the table to itself - you should now have a table with rows like:

```
A|A
A|C
etc.
```

Now put this table into both inputs of a second `Cross Joiner` node, which should give you now quite a long table starting something like:

```
A|A|A|A
A|A|A|C
A|C|A|A
A|C|A|C
etc.
```

Now use a `Column Aggregator` node, select all column as aggregation columns, the aggregation method as `Concatenate` and change the delimiter to an empty string:

[image: Columns setting tab for Column Aggregator]

and:

[image: Options setting tabe for Column Aggregator]

This will give you a table with a single column, 'Peptide':

```
AAAA
AAAC
ACAA
ACAC
etc.
```

If you want the output as a chemical structure, then as of v1.36.0 the Vernalis community contribution contains a node `Speedy Sequence to SMILES` which will convert the sequence to a SMILES string (make sure you select the option that your input column is a Protein!)

The full workflow is as shown:

[image: Workflow]